# What does Chesterton mean by "four letters beginning with a 'R'" in "The Revival of Philosophy – Why"?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-language

In Chesterton's essay "[The Revival of Philosophy – Why?](https://www.chesterton.org/the-revival-of-philosophy-why/)", he wrote:

> [...] not merely by the sound of a syllable or the look of four letters beginning with a “R”.

I wonder what these four letters beginning with an "R" are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R stands for King.  That copy of the essay has a typo in it.  Here is an essay without the typo:  [https://www3.nd.edu/~afreddos/courses/43811/Why%20Philosophy.htm](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/courses/43811/Why%20Philosophy.htm)

> But, anyhow, he will have the habit of testing the thing by the thought; by the idea which he likes or dislikes; and not merely by the sound of a syllable or the look of four letters beginning with a "k".